# Cancel Local Notifications after app is unused for a certain period of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am wondering if it's possible to do what the titles says. I have an application that has a refill reminder to refill your prescription drug via local notifications. I have seen that some apps (pill reminder apps mostly) push a notification if you have not taken your pill, or have not answered back to that notification, and was wondering if I can do the same if a user doesn't open/interact with the app after a certain period of time.

I have not began implementation but have thought about this thoroughly. What I am thinking of doing is having some sort of flag when the app is opened that removes that local notification and sets a new one once the app has gone in the background/inactive. The local notification would be set to three months from when the app has gone in the background/inactive. The question then becomes, how do I handle canceling all notifications after this notification has been received, regardless of whether the user opens the app at that notification or not?

If the user opens the app on that notification, I can have a check the method `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` and then handle the case where that local notification has been set and then use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]`

But if the user does not tap or open the app, how can I check and cancel all local notifications?

Sorry if this is a bit long or worded weirdly (sorry not good with words and explaining things). Let me know if you need more info or better explanation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to keep notifications from repeating when the user does not respond to a notification by opening your app.

You might consider configuring your local notification *not* to repeat. Instead, you might reschedule notification batches each time the application is launched.

Alternatively, if your application has a server-side component, you can use push notifications on iOS 7+ to wake your app, briefly. There is no equivalent to this behavior using UILocalNotification.

Comment: Thanks for replying! The problem is that there are many edge cases for when a user needs to refill their prescription drug so I have to use the repeat value. The only thing I can think of, in order to not use repeat, is to set the local notifications in advance for that 3 month period. The problem now becomes handling the notifications when the user edits their notification or adds new ones. And that seems to be more of a pain with not having repeat.

Comment: Agreed: you would probably want to wipe and reschedule all local notifications on launch.